# How do you install Groovy and Grails plugins for Eclipse/STS without direct internet access?

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

I’m using a Windows 7 Enterprise edition 64 bit, the firewall means certain update sites are not directly accessible and my standard user is not a local admin.

How do you install the Groovy and Grails plugins for STS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update (July 2012)**: There is now a preconfigured version of STS availabe which comes with Groovy and Grails, simply install or unzip the package and Groovy, Grails and their plugins are pre-installed and working. This is available [on the STS site here](http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts) (eg [Groovy/Grails Tool Suite version 3.0.0.M3 zip file is here](http://download.springsource.com/milestone/STS/3.0.0.M3/dist/e4.2/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.0.0.M3-e4.2-win32.zip)

---

I originally had a number of problems with admin/access rights and the inline STS extensions update site getting blocked by the firewall. I thought installing STS as a local admin would help things but this actually made it worse and caused problems when running STS from a normal user account later. Here are the final steps needed…

**User Access Issues:**
Create a directory  eg c:\devtools

1. c:\devtools -> a directory where STS can be installed. (Your Windows 7 User must have full read/write access)
2. Unzipping and all other actions described below should be done as your **normal user** (this doesn’t require a local admin user) A local admin was only needed to create the devtools directory and grant full read/write access to the standard user.

**Download/Firewall Issues:** 
The following files can be downloaded from a separate computer and moved across so the developer PC doesn’t require direct internet access

1. **Download the STS Windows Zip File** http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts

   - Eg STS 2.9.0 / Eclipse 3.7.2, Windows 64 Bit zip file http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/2.9.0/dist/e3.7/springsource-tool-suite-2.9.0.RELEASE-e3.7.2-win32-x86_64.zip
   - Unzip this to your ‘devtools’ directory
2. **Download Groovy STS Plugin** http://ci.repository.codehaus.org/greclipse/snapshot/e37/old/

   - eg Archive v2.6.1 for STS 2.9.0 http://ci.repository.codehaus.org/greclipse/snapshot/e37/old/archive-2.6.1.xx-20120118-1100-e37-M1.zip
   - Go to STS -> Help -> Install New Software -> Click ‘Add’,
   - enter a name, eg ‘STS Groovy Update Zip file’, click ‘Archive’ and select the file that you just downloaded
   - Click ‘Select All’ -> then ‘Next’ -> then ‘Finish’,
   - Accept the confirmations etc then after it has been installed restart STS
3. **Download Eclipse Update Zip File** (which includes the Grails Plugin) (The Groovy Plugin must be installed first) http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts

   - Update Site STS 2.9.0 / Eclipse 3.7.2, eg http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/2.9.0.RELEASE/e3.7/springsource-tool-suite-2.9.0.RELEASE-e3.7.2-updatesite.zip
   - Go to STS -> Help -> Install New Software -> Click ‘Add’, enter a name, eg ‘STS Update Zip file’, click ‘Archive’ and select the file that you just downloaded
   - Select ‘ Core / STS’ ->
   - Click ‘Extensions / STS’ -> ‘SpringSource Tools Suite Grails Support’ then ‘Next’ -> then ‘Finish’
   - Accept the confirmations etc then after it has been installed restart STS

Answer (score 1):

I've found using the Dashboard works for me.  In STS (I'm using 2.9.1, but it worked in 2.8.1 as well and probably earlier), click Help | Dashboard.  Near bottom of that Dashboard, you'll see two tabs [Dashboard] and [Extensions].  Click on Extensions and you get a list of the extensions/plugins that are available.  I'm not sure if this works any differently through the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed STS (v2.9.2) (Eclipse 3.7) from exe (downloaded from www.springsource.org/downloads/sts ) file and followed Chris's response, just changed the address/name like below -
**Groovy STS Plugin:** http://ci.repository.codehaus.org/greclipse/snapshot/e37/old/archive-2.7.0.xx-20120605-0900-e37-RELEASE.zip 
**Grails Support:** http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/2.9.2.RELEASE/e3.7/springsource-tool-suite-2.9.2.RELEASE-e3.7.2-updatesite.zip. 
Though the package explorer is not the same with auto installer, yet it did miracle. Thanks Chris :-)